# Starting counter from 0

Tags: counters, titlesec

I'm working on a sheet of exercises using LaTeX. I've set up my sections to look like `Exercise # | <title>`.

How can I force the section counter to start from 0, so that I can have an exercise 0 explaining how to set up a working environment.

I'm using the titlesec package to format my section headings. I've set \documentclass to `article` to avoid having a numbering that looks like `Exercise 0.x`.

Here is my current formatting:

```
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\section}
  [hang]
  {\huge\bfseries}
  {Exercice \thesection\hsp\textcolor{gray}{|}\hsp}
  {0pt}
  {\large\bfseries}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set your counters to whatever you want with the command `\setcounter{}{}`.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
%%% option 1
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{Exercice \thesection\hsp\textcolor{gray}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\large\bfseries}
%%% option 2
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{Exercice \thesection\hsp\textcolor{gray}{\textbar}\hsp}{0pt}{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{section}{-1}
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `T1` font encoding the `|` looks as it should be.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi With `\textbar` instead of `|` there won't be any encodiong problem at all (I think).